# Appharbor live deployment of builds

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msdeploy, appharbor

What is the best strategy to deploy the latest build to the AppHarbor live site without users seeing any error while the deployment is in progress. Worker process will always be restarted when you deploy a fresh build though. What is the recommended strategy here.

How does StackOverflow deploy builds or bug-fixes to the live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're currently getting errors when deploying new versions using AppHarbor, then please get in touch so that we can take a look.

Worker restarts should not cause errors as such, just some initial slowness for the first users accessing the site after a deploy. We're also working on hot-swaps so that we only switch over to the new version once the workers are all warmed up and running.

Comment: I did see 500 once but its not appearing that often now. Will post it next time I see. Appreciate your timely responses. Can you also explain how exactly hot-swaps work.

Comment: Here's a blog post describing the pre-warming feature: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/09/04/web-worker-pre-warming